# How to generate access token on user register in Loopback Express framework?

Tags: express, token, loopback

Loopback generates access token on default User /login method, my question is how to override default register strategy to add token generating? I'm using middleware to get current user like this

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if ( ! req.accessToken) return next();
  app.models.Account.findById(req.accessToken.userId, function(err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if ( ! user) return next(new Error('No user with this access token was found.'));
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
});
```

but I'm right after user registered req.accessToken is undefined; after user login everything works

Comment: can you please elaborate its unclear on what you are looking at ?

Comment: after User logged in, loopback automatically generates access token, for instance {
  "id": "GOkZRwgZ61q0XXVxvxlB8TS1D6lrG7Vb9V8YwRDfy3YGAN7TM7EnxWHqdbIZfheZ",
  "ttl": 1209600,
  "created": "2013-12-20T21:10:20.377Z",
  "userId": 1
} . Thus, I'm able to get current user in server.js by adding a middleware (code provided above). But this access token is not automatically generated after User registered. (Loopback returns email and password instead). I need to generate access token after registration, too

Comment: ohh at the time of creating a new user ?

Comment: Yes, I need to generate access token after creating a new user